# ¿Como puedo ajustar automaticamente el tamaño de un label a un frame?

Tags: c++, qt

intento ajustar automáticamente el tamaño de un `label` a la ventana principal, estoy usando `lay out horizontally` pero cambia la dimensión tanto de ancho como de alto, yo solo quiero que se auto ajuste en lo alto y no en lo ancho

Asi es como quiero que quede

[image: Asi es como quiero que quede]

Asi es como queda

[image: Asi es como queda]

Comment: ¿Que ancho debe tener y cual seria la posicion de la esquina izquierda-superior del QLabel?

Comment: ancho de 160, y la izquierda seria de x=250, y=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es la primera vez que respondo con imágenes. Te pongo el ejemplo hecho en QDesigner. Si es con código, no tiene mucho problema tampoco:

La idea es tener el `QLabel` entre dos `horizontalSpacer` y los tres elementos dentro de un `QHBoxLayout`, y a su vez ajustarlo al widget con otro layout.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que el `QLabel`  tenga un ancho definido, hay que ajustar el tamaño a ese ancho (`minimumSize` y `maximumSize`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si quieres una distancia fija a la esquina superior izquierda, puedes ajustarla en el `horizontalSpacer` de la izquierda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]